# Preload tab with # in url using jQuery .tabs() with Ajax

Tags: jquery

It's obvious this works for non-ajax tabs: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/default.html#tabs-2

But how do you get this working for ajax tabs, as shown in this example:  http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ajax.html

I tried giving the `<a name="">`, that didn't quite work, just curious what's the best way to get this functionilty of using the # in the url to preload a tab with ajax tabs in jquery?

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to access www.example.com/#tab3 and load the tab3 with ajax?

Comment: yes, but something preferably native to the original .tabs() functionality.

Comment: What you mean by preferably native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works exactly the same with ajax tabs too:

Visit this page: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ajax.html#ui-tabs-2 and note that the content shown is loaded with ajax.

Comment: The above link seems to be not working. You can check here: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax